# How to find elements which end with space and value by xpath

Tags: java, xpath

I tried to get all elements which end with symbol '3' like this `1 3`
To do it I wrote this xpath

```
(//table)[2]//tr/td[position() = 7  and substring(., (string-length(.) - string-length(' 3')) + 2) = ' 3']
```

but it doesn't work.
P.S I try to rewrite function ends-with that is unavailable in xpath 1.0
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please specify problem a little bit more?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it with xpath 1.0, but this code should work in java: http://pastebin.com/uTwTLfPB

Comment: @xenteros There is a table and I need filter it by class(td[position()=7]) with value '3'. in this cell can be many variant of number combination like
`3`,`1 3 4`,`3 4`,`1 3`. first three combinations I cover but with last I have a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition which you've written is incorrect. Try the condition below.

```
"... [position() = 7 and substring(., string-length(.) - string-length(' 3') + 1) = ' 3']"
```

Notice that I've changed the `+2` to `+1`.

Have a look at the examples below:

```
> $x("substring('1 2 3', string-length('1 2 3') - string-length(' 3') + 2)")
"3"

> $x("substring('1 2 3', 5-2+2)")
"3"
```

Notice that the value of the second parameter to the `substring` function is `5`. Hence, it returns the string from 5<sup>th</sup> index (Do note that in XPath the first index is considered as `1`), i.e. `"3"`.

To get `" 3"`, simply add 1 instead of 2.

```
> $x("substring('1 2 3', string-length('1 2 3') - string-length(' 3') + 1)")
" 3"
```